# If $\epsilon\colon X\to Y$ is both a zero morphism and an epimorphism in a semicategory, is $Y$ a zero object?

Tags: category-theory

Suppose $\mathcal{C}$ is a semicategory (i.e., we don't assume the existence of identity arrows) with a zero object.

If $\epsilon\colon X\to Y$ is both a zero morphism and an epimorphism, is $Y$ a zero object? It is quick to see that $Y$ is an initial object, since precomposing any parallel arrows $Y\to Z$ with $\epsilon$ give the (unique) zero map $0_{XZ}\colon X\to Z$, and $\epsilon$ is right cancellative.

But in a semicategory, the unique endomorphism on an initial object need not be the identity, and without that two initial objects need not be isomorphic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the semicategory with three objects $0,Y,Z$, where we have a zero morphism between any two of these, but we also have a random other morphism $f:Z\to Y$.
This makes $0$ the only zero object ($f$ makes neither $Y$ nor $Z$ a zero object), and composition is easy: you always get a zero map just due to the lack of non-zero maps.

In this situation, we can see that $Y$ is an initial object: the only maps $Y\to0$, $Y\to Y$, and $Y\to Z$ are zero maps.
This implies that $0\to Y$ is an epimorphism (and it's also a zero morphism), and we have already established that $Y$ is not a zero object.